# Avoid insert new record in solr. only need to update record

Tags: solr

I am updating particular field in solr. I want update product information in solr only if record is available. I used curl call to update record.

Current Behaviour: If record is not available in solr record is getting inserted to solr. Which is not necessary

Solr document structure is:

```
{
        "ID":"62798",
        "NAME":"Clothing",
        "SKU":"123",
        "HitCount":0
},
{
        "ID":"62798",
        "NAME":"Clothing",
        "SKU":"231",
        "HitCount":1
}
```

following is curl call to update record:

```
curl 'localhost:8983/solr/update?commit=true' -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '[{"SKU":"432","HitCount":{"set":5}}]'
```

In above call **SKU:432** is not available in solr but i get following output:

```
    {
            "ID":"62798",
            "NAME":"Clothing",
            "SKU":"123",
            "HitCount":0
    },
    {
            "ID":"62798",
            "NAME":"Clothing",
            "SKU":"231",
            "HitCount":1
    },
    {
            "SKU":"432",
            "HitCount":5
    }
```

If SKU:432 not found in solr then this record should not inserted to solr.
How can i achieve this ?

Comment: you have to perform a check and run the update operation...In one call it wont be possible

Comment: You should be able to make this work by using the `_version_` field with a value of `1` as shown in the optimistic concurrency examples: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_6/updating-parts-of-documents.html#optimistic-concurrency - that way the document has to exist before being updated.